# build.gradle.kts & multi-module-project: how to add other project so that transitive dependencies are available too

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Having the following multi-module-setup:

```
multi
├── projA
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── projB
│   └── build.gradle.kts
├── build.gradle.kts
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

with the following content (abbreviated):

- `settings.gradle.kts`

  ```
  rootProject.name = "multi"
  include("projA", "projB")
  ```
- `projA\build.gradle.kts`

  ```
  dependencies {
      implementation("important-library:1.0")
  }
  ```
- `projB\build.gradle.kts`

  ```
  dependencies {
      implementation(project(":projA"))
  }
  ```

Why don't I have access to that `importantlibrary:1.0` from `projB`?

What works: if I have a class within `projA` that uses the library, it works perfectly even if that class is called from a class within `projB` (so indirect access works). Directly accessing any class from `importantlibrary:1.0` within `projB` doesn't work (unresolved reference).

What am I missing here? Or what needs to be set up so that it works?

Gradle version: 5.6.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think a good way to achieve what you want would be to use `api` instead of `implementation`. `implementation` is meant to only keep the dependency inside the module, while `api` is meant to export them along with the module. The dependencies for `projA` would then become:

```
dependencies {
    api("important-library:1.0")
}
```

This is the link to the official documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation

Comment: can you elaborate on that a bit further? I mean this is certainly working for the classes in question, but the next step would be to build a fat jar... which dependencies should then be included and which not? how would you resolve that? Coming from Maven I thought `compile` would be replaceable with `implementation` and `provided` with `api` ... and it nearly worked out... the `configuration = "default"` resolved the last issue and now it all seems to work similar as it worked in Maven...

Comment: if my assumption is wrong however, then I am all ears, how it actually should be and how I would resolve something like a fat jar...

Comment: Seems as if my assumption was not correct... need to study more :-) will clean up some comments...

Answer (score 4):

I found lots of sources mentioning `configuration` to handle how transitive dependencies are dealt with. Digging deeper I found that the default configuration should make the `runtime`, `runtimeOnly` and `implementation` available to the referencing project.

Either I misinterpreted "default" here or you really need to call it using the `"default"`-configuration explicitly. Declaring the dependency as follows in `projB`, made the dependencies from `projA` available to `projB` as well:

```
implementation(project(":projA", "default"))
// or with named parameters:
implementation(project(path = ":projA", configuration = "default"))
```

Wondering whether this is/was really intended or whether that is rather an unfortunate default value for the `configuration`-parameter of the `project`-function.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 themes: transitivity of dependencies and `/src` as dependency

- ## Dependency transitivity

We use `api` so that the dependency can be exported to the higher hierarchy of modules.

### build.gradle.kts (:library_base)

```
dependencies {
    api("group", "name", "version")
}
```

---

### build.gradle.kts (:common)

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":domain"))
    implementation(project(":library_base"))
}
```

- ## Transitivity of /src as dependency

We pass `"default"` in the second parameter as configuration to be able to import the `/src` from the lower hierarchy of modules.

### build.gradle.kts (:feature_a)

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":common", "default"))
}
```

To be able to access from `:feature_a` to `/src` of eg. `:domain` we use `"default"` as configuration and to be able to access the dependencies of `:library_base` we make sure that they are defined with `api` in that module so that they can be exported.

GL

[Source](https://github.com/Coronel-B/Moebius-backend)